# Android chroot ubuntu - is it possible to get ubuntu to recognise usb devices

Tags: linux, file-system, usb-drivers, usb-peripherals

I've managed to setup the chroot but I'm unsure how to get the chroot to recognise usb devices. I'll be doing so work with microcontrollers hence I neeed to to recognise my usb based programmer.

For starters how do I populate the dev directory with the host dev directory(android)?

Is it then just a matter of getting the right kernel modules loaded?

I'm running prime1.5 firmware on the asus transformer

Answer (score 2):

To populate /dev, use a bind mount (rbind=recursive bind, to catch `/dev/pts`):

```
outside# mount --rbind /dev /path/to/chroot/dev
```

You may also want to bind other things, like `/home` and `/tmp` (to make sharing files easier). Just remember to unmount them before `rm -Rf`'ing your chroot!

You can put bind mounts in fstab. I believe that'd look something like this:

```
/dev   /chroot/dev   none   rbind   0   0
```

You may need to set up `udev` to set proper permissions on your USB device. For example, here are the udev rules I use for my phone:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/local-android.rules
ACTION!="add", GOTO="local-android_rules_end"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", GOTO="local-android_rules_real"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", GOTO="local-android_rules_real"
GOTO="local-android_rules_end"

LABEL="local-android_rules_real"

# Mot Droid X
ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", ATTR{idProduct}=="428c", MODE="660", GROUP="plugdev"

LABEL="local-android_rules_end"
```

Comment: [Here's a more complete guide on adding Android devices to udev](http://www.mysolutions.it/mounting-android-sd-card-ubuntu/), for most devices.