# Access to android usb port from chroot linux?

Tags: usb, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android chroot ubuntu - is it possible to get ubuntu to recognise usb devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11546/android-chroot-ubuntu-is-it-possible-to-get-ubuntu-to-recognise-usb-devices)

IS it possible to communicate over the real USB port of an android host when running linux in chroot?